# file field text issue in safari

Tags: html, css

I need to change `"no file selected" to "No file selected"` in **safari browser**. It is good in chrome and Firefox. How to fix this. Please see my screenshot image.
[image].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*If it ain't borken, don't fix.*

There is nothing to fix here.  It works as designed: The controls show what the browser vendor intended, and what the users of that browser expect.  *In their preferred language.*  Do not try to mess with that.  HTML does not give you what you want, but what the user needs.  CSS also can only help you so far.

You could hide the control and build your own control based on it, using client-side scripting.  But I strongly recommend against that because it may not work reliably, if at all.  I have tried.

You would also have to do the i18n then – do you speak the preferred language of all your target users?